# How can I sort between characters and numbers in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
IRB 360
IRB 6620
IRB 6700
IRB1600
IRB1600ID 
IRB 1200
IRB 2400
IRB 2600
IRB 8700
IRB1660ID
IRB 4400
NULL
IRB 6660
IRB1600/1660
IRB 6650
IRB 120
IRB 14000
IRB 1410
IRB 1520
IRB 7600
IRB140
IRB1600ID/1660ID
IRB 910SC
IRB 6640
IRB 4600
```

### How can I sort the above data with SQL query as follows. I tried `order by asc desc`.

```
NULL
IRB 120
IRB 140
IRB 360
IRB 910SC
IRB 1200
IRB 1410
IRB 1520
IRB 1600
IRB 1600/1660
IRB 1600ID 
IRB 1600ID/1660ID
IRB 1660ID
IRB 2400
IRB 2600
IRB 4400
IRB 4600
IRB 6620
IRB 6640
IRB 6650
IRB 6660
IRB 6700
IRB 7600
IRB 8700

IRB 14000

Select distinct Robot_Type
From [dbo].[Information]
ORDER BY Robot_Type desc
```

I wrote that part wrong. IRB 910SC is not bigger than IRB 1200.There was a confusion, but the following two answers solved the problem.
| RobotType|
| -------- |
| First    |
| Second   |

Comment: how can i make character rank

Comment: Can you explain the rules for the desired order, e.g. why is `'IRB 910SC'` greater than `'IRB 1200'`? If not, it's awfully hard to help you.

Comment: I wrote that part wrong. IRB 910SC is not bigger than IRB 1200.There was a confusion, but the following two answers solved the problem. @HABO

Comment: ok i didn't know this, i will do that @DaleK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option

**Example**

```
Select Robot_Type
 from (Select distinct Robot_Type 
        From  YourTable
      ) A
 Order By try_convert(int,left(replace(Robot_Type,'IRB',''),patindex('%[a-z,/]%',replace(Robot_Type,'IRB','')+'a')-1))
      ,Robot_Type
```

Returns

```
Robot_Type
NULL
IRB 120
IRB140
IRB 360
IRB 910SC   ---<< Disconnect from your desired results
IRB 1200
IRB 1410
IRB 1520
IRB1600
IRB1600/1660
IRB1600ID
IRB1600ID/1660ID
IRB1660ID
IRB 2400
IRB 2600
IRB 4400
IRB 4600
IRB 6620
IRB 6640
IRB 6650
IRB 6660
IRB 6700
IRB 7600
IRB 8700
IRB 14000
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want. The explanation is in the comments.

```
select Robot_Type
from (
  select Robot_Type, ':' + coalesce(Robot_Type,'') + ':' TestName
  from [dbo].[Information] T
) T
-- Find the first digit
cross apply (values (patindex('%[0-9]%',T.TestName))) as M(N)
-- Find the first non-digit following the first digit 
cross apply (values (patindex('%[^0-9]%',substring(T.TestName,M.N,len(T.TestName)))-1)) as N(N)
-- Extract the number
cross apply (values (case when M.N > 0 then convert(int,substring(T.TestName,M.N,N.N)) else null end)) as O(N)
-- Order by the number
order by O.N, Robot_Type;
```